# league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 conflict with Laravel 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

My current composer.json is

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "symfony/http-client": "^6.3",
    "symfony/mailgun-mailer": "^6.3",
    "twilio/sdk": "^7.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
},
```

And I'm trying to install S3 package by running this command

`composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3`

But getting this error

```
 Problem 1
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[3.12.1, ..., 3.15.0] require aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.220.0 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.220.0, ..., 3.275.9].
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[3.0.0, ..., 3.10.3] require aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.132.4 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.132.4, ..., 3.275.9].
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.13] require league/flysystem ~1.0 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.10] but the package is fixed to 3.15.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.15, ..., 1.0.30] require league/flysystem ^1.0.40 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.40, ..., 1.1.10] but the package is fixed to 3.15.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0, ..., 2.5.0] require league/flysystem ^2.0.0 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0, ..., 2.5.0] but the package is fixed to 3.15.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - aws/aws-sdk-php[3.131.0, ..., 3.173.19] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.4.1 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.4.1, ..., 1.9.1] but the package is fixed to 2.5.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - aws/aws-sdk-php[3.173.20, ..., 3.198.8] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.7.0, ..., 1.9.1] but the package is fixed to 2.5.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - aws/aws-sdk-php[3.199.0, ..., 3.275.9] require guzzlehttp/promises ^1.4.0 -> found guzzlehttp/promises[1.4.0, ..., 1.5.3] but the package is fixed to 2.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 * -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.30, 2.0.0, ..., 2.5.0, 3.0.0, ..., 3.15.0].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3:^2.1" if you know which you need.
```

Also try with --ignore-platform-reqs but same error.

Answer (score 2):

Problem fixed by using this command

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^3.0" --with-all-dependencies
```